# SOLR 6.6 - Plugin Initializing failure

Tags: magento, solr, character-encoding, lucene

I am using SOLR with Magento an I have problem:

1. While I get alphabetically sorted data from SOLR **it's using latin alphabet and I would like to get it in polish,** so

I want: a, b, c...s, ś...z but i get:
a, b, c...s...z, ś

Note: 'ś' is polish character, it falls after 's'.

**2. So I change in schema.xml** my text field from

```
<fieldType name="edgytext" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="200">
```

to: `<fieldType name="edgytext" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="200" locale="pl_PL" strength="secondary">`

Just like documentation says.[1](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/language-analysis.html#LanguageAnalysis-SortingTextforaSpecificLanguage)

Before that, I added

```
<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>
```

to solrconfig.xml so it could use schema.xml instead of managed-schema

**3. After reloading core I get:**

polish: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core polish: Can't load schema /usr/local/solr-6.6.2/server/solr/polish/conf/schema.xml: Plugin Initializing failure for [schema.xml] fieldType

I would be extremely grateful for some guidance.

Comment: Are you sure the locale attribute is supported with solr.TextField? I know only examples where locale is used with solr.ICUCollationField.

Comment: I have noticed that, right now I'm trying to solve the error message problem, so I have created some test fieldType:
<fieldType name="testtest" class="solr.ICUCollationField" locale="pl_PL" strength="secondary"/>
And the result is still the same.

Comment: Your error message should contain far more information about exactly _what_ failed. Look further down in the stack trace.

Comment: you should expose a bigger portion of your schema.xml

Comment: Also be aware that you're linking to the documentation as a reference for "this is how it should work", but you're linking to the documentation for `solr.ICUCollationField` and not for `solr.TextField` which you are using in your definition. Those field types are not identical.